# Updating a field in Parent Object from a child object

Tags: process-builder

I don't have experience using Process builder but I believe based on everything I read that this may allow me to update a custom field in the Account object based on a count I would do in a child object, in this case a custom contact object used by my app. Thus, what I am trying to do is have the count of records coming from the child object displayed in a custom field in the Account object (parent).

Comment: Why dont you use roll ups ?

Comment: Hi Ricardo, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful.

Comment: Is the child object joined by a Master Detail or Lookup relationship to the parent object?

Comment: @DaveHumm, it is joined by a Lookup relationship

Comment: @erkançipil, not familiar with Roll-ups. What does that entail? I've been using SFDC for a long time but more as a user than a dev/administrator. What's an example of how that would work?

Comment: @Ricardo - Rollup summary fields can be used in Master Detail relationships to count detail records under the master record including summarising the values of field from the detail records.  SF help on these https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en